# How fix bug - login with facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

I did login with facebook in the Activity

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginFBButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LAYOUT);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginFBButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginFBButton);
    loginFBButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    loginFBButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            LogTag.v("onSuccess - getToken - " + accessToken);
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            LogTag.v("onSuccess - " + response.toString());

                            // Application code
                            try {
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                LogTag.v("email - " + email);
                                String name = object.getString("name");
                                LogTag.v("name - " + name);
                                saveUserData(name, email, accessToken);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            LogTag.v("onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            LogTag.v("onError - " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

in gradle

```
dependencies { compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0' }
```

in AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application
    android:name=".application.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ActivitySignIn"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</application>
```

in MyApp

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
}   }
```

but it does not always work on 4.4.2 - OK, in the phone (5.1) on one normal and the other hangs after login with a progress bar under which there is a notice of confirmation of access to personal data, and then triggers onCancel

On your phone, which it might be a bug in the log shows a link to the message:

```
{       "error": {
  "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 104,
  "fbtrace_id": "AV/53FbmMya"       }   }
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i use in fragment.

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
                            .getToken();
                    Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "on Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "on Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    IRoidAppHelper.Log("FacebokkError", exception.toString());
                }
            });`
```

Comment: just remove Fb SDK initialized in Application class

Comment: just remove Fb SDK initialized in Application class - I do this .
what it the error? - no error, run onCancel .

When running a fragment in the log:

{
   "supports_implicit_sdk_logging": true,
   "gdpv4_nux_content": "New! You're in control - choose what info you want to share with apps.",
   "gdpv4_nux_enabled": false,
   "gdpv4_chrome_custom_tabs_enabled": true,
   "android_dialog_configs": {
{
            "name": "com.facebook.platform.action.request.LIKE_DIALOG|LIKE_DIALOG",
            "url": "/connect/dialog/MPlatformLikeJSDialog",

Comment: "versions": [
               "20140701"
            ]
         },
         {
            "name": "com.facebook.platform.action.request.APPINVITES_DIALOG|APP_INVITES_DIALOG",
            "url": "/connect/dialog/MPlatformAppInvitesJSDialog",
            "versions": [
               "20140701"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "android_sdk_error_categories": [
      {
         "name": "login_recoverable",
         "items": [
            {
               "code": 102
            },
            {
               "code": 190
            }
         ],

Comment: "recovery_message": "Please log into this app again to reconnect your Facebook account."
      }
   ],
   "app_events_session_timeout": 60,
   "id": "114470178966813"
}